# Networkx : global efficiency after deleting a node

Tags: performance, networkx

I am a beginner with networkx and Python as well, and I would like to iterate over a graph's nodes, in each iteration I would like to delete a node, calculate the global efficiency of the graph after deleting the node, and adding this node before doing the same processus with the other nodes. I have tried this script, but I noticed that after removing some nodes , the calculated global efficiency is larger than the initial global efficiency of the graph ( without deleting any node ). Is this normal, or there is a mistake in my script ?

Thanks in advance

```
a=nx.global_efficiency(H)

for elt in H.nodes():
       e=nx.global_efficiency(H.subgraph(set(H)-{i}))
       print ( e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks fine. It is possible to get larger global efficiency by deleting a node.

Here is a minimal example to show it:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0, 2), (2, 1)])

# Efficiency of: 0 -> 2 -> 1 :
print(nx.global_efficiency(G)) # 0.8333333333333334

# Efficiency of: 2 -> 1
print(nx.global_efficiency(G.subgraph(set(G)-{0}))) # 1.0
```

The graph's global efficiency is computed as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(network_science)).